# How to restore chrome extension user data without backup?

Tags: google-chrome, data-recovery, google-chrome-extensions

I already reinstalled the extension so the previous data were now replaced. I do not have any back up, how can I still get the data from my previous extension?

Comment: You don't; When you deleted the folder containing the extension data it was permanently deleted.  In the future, you should backup important data, before you delete it.

Comment: @Ramhound is there really no advanced way? It's my metamask data I have not saved the seed phrase :/

Comment: You can try standard file recovery software.  However, as you write data to your HDD, it will eventually be overwritten. You will have to decide which file recovery software you want to use.

Comment: @Ramhound I already did and nothing shows...I wonder where I went wrong